# How can i save the parameters after and URL like id=3&name=blla to a database so later i can call that values to show in any page in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I used this code

```
<%
// retrieves query string values    
string WebID = Page.Request.QueryString["WebID"];    
string Name = Page.Request.QueryString["Name"];    
string Surname = Page.Request.QueryString["Surname"];    

Page.Response.Write("<h1> WebId: "+WebID+" , Name: "+Name+" , Surname: "+Surname+" </h1>");    
%>)
```

i can just see the `Page.Response.Write` with parameters, but how can i insert these values inside database when the page loads, which means im getting an url, and i want that url to be directly inserted in database

Comment: It all depends on what your database is and how you want to connect to it. Then it should be pretty straight forward. Please be more specific.

Comment: well im using Microsoft Visual  Web Developer express to make a web, i have created  database.mdl which is SQL Database , and i need to take the url like this default.aspx?WebID=2&Name=test&Surname=test1 i want to get the values 2 and test and test1 from that url , put inside database and then i can call from database to show them in any asp page i need, i think this is enough info

Comment: i made a mobile app and im sending that url to server, so i want to take parameters from url put inside database and show them in website, this is the path i want to create, the mobile part is done, now i need that parameters to put in database to save them and show in my web page

Comment: i solved i think my self lol , for further infos i did like this

dim WebID as String = Covert.toString(Page.Request.QueryString("WebID"))